# MySQL row inserted but not saved?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a row into a MySQL table from PHP and running a query right after the insert to get the key value of the row that was just inserted like so:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user(vFirstName, vLastName, vEmail, vPassword, iSkilllevelid, vTournaments, vDays, dAddedDate, eStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,4,'Pick-Up','Saturday',NOW(),'Active')");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $pwd);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT iUserId FROM user WHERE vEmail=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($iUserId);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    break;
}
```

After this code executes, `$iUserId` has the correct auto incremented key value (1143 for instance), but when I actually look at the database table, the row with that key (1143) does not exist. How is that possible??

Comment: Which MySQL engine are you using? My first guess would be "transaction isolation".

Comment: My guess is you are referring to different table on mysql :P

Comment: What PHP library are you using for MySQL?

Comment: did you forget to commit;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting from the table after insertion, you should use [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```php
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('
  INSERT INTO user
    (vFirstName, vLastName, vEmail, vPassword, iSkilllevelid,
       vTournaments, vDays, dAddedDate, eStatus)
  VALUES
    (?,?,?,?,4,"Pick-Up","Saturday",NOW(),"Active")
');
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $pwd);
$stmt->execute();
$iUserId = $this->db->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
```

As to why the inserted data is not appearing from other connections, it seems likely that your transaction has not been committed:

```php
$this->db->commit();
```

Comment: Thank you! Missing the commit was the issue.